# What makes throughput of the SFTP and SCP protocols different

Tags: networking, scp, ssh2-sftp

In windows, I have transferred a data file (8GB) with sftp and scp (secure copy protocol) and get result like this:

[image: Link speed is 1000 Mbps]

[image: I'm getting this data from Wireshark filter by SSHv2 Protocol]

and calculated throughput = data size/time(sec)

[image: this is throughput of both protocol]

I'm a newbie in networking. I don't know what makes the throughput of these protocols different? I think this is not about interactive and non-interactive, because in debugging file, I seen command line during transferring file are same.  Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: thank. you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the protocols are based on SSH. And SSH [itself has some overhead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell#/media/File:Ssh_binary_packet_alt.svg):
[image: wiki]

SCP is really naive protocol with really naive algorithm for transferring a few of small files. It has a lot of synchronization (RTT - Round Trip Time) and small buffers (basically 2048 B -- [source](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/scp.c#L763)).

SFTP on the other side more advanced and more ready for transferring files. It has bigger buffers which decreases need for synchronization and increases speed. I guess you would achieve similar results with `rsync`, which is probably the most appropriate tool to transfer data. [Buffer has by default 32 768 B](http://rc.quest.com/man.php?id=sftp%281%29) = 32 kB, but it is configured on commandline using `-B` switch.

Comment: You are welcome. But using "handsome" in this context is probably not appropriate ;)

Comment: @Jakuje Oh, c'mon, OP obviously meant that moose in your avatar's pretty handsome :P